# Mod_Rewrite for URL with multiple variables

Tags: variables, mod-rewrite, mask

I have the following code in my .htaccess

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ index.php?mode=$1&%{QUERY_STRING})

It works great for one variable but I want to pass some additional variables and would like them to so up like the first one. So instead of having /about/?anotherVar=extra I have /about/extra. The additional variable would be on some pages not all

I now have:

```
#<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

#   RewriteEngine on
#    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

#</IfModule>


Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ index.php?mode=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ index.php?mode=$1&productContent=$2 [QSA]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ index.php?mode=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ index.php?mode=$1&anotherVar=$2 [QSA]
```

PS the QSA replaces the `&%{QUERY_STRING}`

Comment: So I would need to replace "anotherVar" with whatever mine will be?

Comment: I gave that I try and it doesn't seem to want to work. The following works: /products?productContent=oliveOil but if I try to change it to /products/oliveOil then it won't work.

Comment: I should be a little more clear. It works and it loads my page, but I lose parts of my page. I have used <?php include("template.php") ?> on the index page and the mode variable loads the content infomation into the template.php. When I go to add /oliveOil to the URL it loads the right page but does not load the template.php. Is there a solution to this or will I have to stick to using /products?productContent=oliveOil in the URL?

Comment: I fixed it!! It wasn't the template.php that was the issue it was all my image and css links that were the problem. Added the domain name in front and all is well. Thanks.

Comment: Glad you figured it out. Might I suggest using root relative urls. It's shorter, and makes your live easier if you every change your domain-name, or switch to https. So e.g. `<img src="/images/sample.jpg" />` instead of `<img src="http://example.com/images/sample.jpg" />`

Comment: I agree and I usually do, but it was not working when I had the root relative urls. I had to use the domain as well.