# mod_rewrite for URL with more than one variable

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Hi i'm trying to follow [Mod_Rewrite for URL with multiple variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15314832/mod-rewrite-for-url-with-multiple-variables) and edit it to suit my website but have a bit of a problem i have searched across the internet and could not really find anything which helps

I'm trying to turn example.com/editor/windows/chrome into this  example.com?app=editor&os=windows&browser=chrome

Any ideas?

my current .htaccess file:

```
# Various rewrite rules.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ index.php?app=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ index.php?app=$1&os=$2&browser=$3 [QSA]
</IfModule>
```

I can get it to part work up-to example.com/editor/windows but can't get the third to include the browser

Answer (score 2):

Your third rule doesn't include a capture group for the browser. This statement is missing:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?app=$1&os=$2&browser=$3 [QSA]
```

RewriteRules are applied from top to bottom until [L] is found. Thus, in your question both rules are applied (which might casue bad performance).

A more clean version would be,

```
# Various rewrite rules.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

# don't rewrite URLs for existing files, directories or links
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
RewriteRule .* - [L]

# now match the URIs according to OP needs
# Redirect example.com/editor and example.com/editor/ to example.com/index.php?app=editor and stop after this rule
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ index.php?app=$1 [QSA,L]
# Redirect example.com/editor/windows and example.com/editor/windows/ to example.com/index.php?app=editor&os=windows and stop after this rule
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ index.php?app=$1&os=$2 [QSA,L]
# Redirect example.com/editor/windows/chrome and example.com/editor/windows/chrome/ to example.com/index.php?app=editor&os=windows&browser=chrome and stop after this rule
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ index.php?app=$1&os=$2&browser=$3 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

However, the last three `RewriteRule` rules can also be compiled to one:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)(?:/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)(?:/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)))/?$ index.php?app=$1&os=$2&browser=$3 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: You should explain how conditions are applied to rules, not compound the error.  The easiest is to negate the conds and `[OR]` them so the first cond becomes `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]` and then follow these by `RewriteRule ^ - [LAST, NC]`

Comment: it was a straigt question here why the third case was not matching. The other rules indicated to me that the OP knows what these other rules indicated.

Comment: @TerryE I don't understand why you gave me -1 immediately without first discussing it (see other answers on this page). I tried hard to explain the reason for it (as opposed to other answers)

Comment: It's easy for me to flip a -1.  I still get penalised for downvoting, but you'll remember my point. But I still prefer Jon Lin's soln.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you don't mind having blank `$_GET[]` variables, you can reduce it all down to a single rule. Also not that you have 2 conditions that check for `!-f` and `!-d`. Those conditions **only apply to the immediately following rule**, and will not apply to any other rules unless you duplicate the condition.

So you can try:

```
# Various rewrite rules.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)(?:/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)|)(?:/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)|)/?$ index.php?app=$1&os=$2&browser=$3 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```